# How to validate extra field in form? CAKEPHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am creating a form with a check box called "agreement". The user must click this to confirm that he has agreed to the agreements. But how do I add this to the validation? Can I do this from the model? This is a field that is not in the database.

In cake 2.0 I could do it like this:

```
$this->Model->set($this->data['Form']['agree']);
if($this->Model->validates($this->data)){
  // okay
  $this->Model->Save();
}else{
  pr($this->Model->invalidFields());
}
```

How to do it in cakephp 3?

Answer (score 0):

In model you can add custom patch method, that will check 'confirm' field in request->data. if it's empty then just call errors('data.confirm'). So your entity will have errors, and you just need to render this error to your form. Something like:

```
public function customPatch($data) {
$entity = $this->newEntity($data);
    if (!$entity->confirm) {
        $entity->errors('data.confirm', 'You have to...');
    }
    return $entity;
}
```